# Probability of rolling a fair dice m times to get a specific number n times.

Tags: probability

I am tasked with the following series of questions.

Find the probability of each of the following:

1. Rolling 6 dice and getting at least one 3.
2. Rolling 12 dice and getting at least two 3s.
3. Rolling 18 dice and getting at least three 3s.

I am able to solve the first one. $P(A) = (1/6) + (1/6)(5/6) +... (1/6)(5/6)^5$. I then apply the geometric progression formula.
However, I can't seem to find a good way to solve questions 2 and 3 even though they look similar to the first one. I am probably missing some pattern, so I would appreciate any ideas for solving these questions.

edit: 
I have attempted questions 2 and 3 by considering the opposite case, as suggested by one of the comments. But I got a counter intuitive result. Would appreciate any help in verifying if my method is correct.

2) $P($Rolling 12 dice and getting at most 1 '3'$) 
= (5/6)^{12} + (\binom{12}{1})(1/6)(5/6)^{11}$

$P($Rolling 12 dice and getting at least 2 '3's$) 
= 1 - ($ANS ABOVE$) = 0.6187$

3)  $P($Rolling 18 dice and getting at most 2 '3's) 
 $= (5/6)^{18} + (\binom{18}{1})(1/6)(5/6)^{17} + (\binom{18}{2})(1/6)^2(5/6)^{16}$

$P($Rolling 18 dice and getting at least 3 '3's$)
= 1 - ($ANS ABOVE$) = 0.5973$

My answer for question 1 is $0.5981$, so this trend seems a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: Hint: can you figure out the probabilities that you get (respectively) no threes, at most one three, or at most two threes?

Comment: That is a good idea, thanks!

Comment: I think you computed $1-(5/6)^5\approx0.5981$ instead of $1-(5/6)^6$.

Comment: @BobSleigh Maybe it is counter-intuitive, but it is true. If you multiply the number of rolls and the number of successes by a constant $c$, then $P(X \geq c \cdot k| c\cdot n)<P(X \geq  k|  n)$ for $c\in \mathbb N^+ \backslash \{ 1\}$

Comment: Yup, I got the first one wrong. I used the geometric progression formula for 5 terms instead of 6 terms.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a binomial distribution $n=6,12,18. p=\frac16$

$P[n,k]=\binom{n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$

Answer to your first question[at least one 3 in 6 rolls] is **1-P[6,0]**=$\frac{31031}{46656}$

Answer to your second question[at least two 3s in 12 rolls] is **1-P[12,0]-P[12,1]**= $\frac{1028975}{1663212}$

and answer to your third question[at least three 3s in 18 rolls] is **1-P[18,0]-P[18,1]-P[18,2]**=$\frac{659343}{1103788}$

Comment: Sorry, I think you may have misread the question.

Comment: @BobSleigh, Do you have answers provided by the author to  all of your three questions?

Comment: The question is to find the probability for each of the following:
1. Rolling 6 dice and getting at least one 3.
2. Rolling 12 dice and getting at least two 3s.
3. Rolling 18 dice and getting at least three 3s.